# How to understand typescript index signature?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

if I have a type like this

```
{[index: string]: number}
```

this means that keys for my object can be **string** and value will be **number**.

I wanted to know if this word `index` has any significance eg, is there a difference between the following two types

```
{[index: string]: number}
```

and

```
{[key: string]: number}
```

It will be great if some reference can be provided from docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `index` is just a name that is assigned to indicate the index. Practically both the types are same.

Comment: thanks very much, can you provide any reference for this ?

Comment: you may find this helpful https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html

Comment: the text on the left hand side of `:` is an identifier. The one on the right specifies the type.

Comment: i dont understand  the point of that identifier when "the identifier itself can be anything".

Comment: You need to have something on the left hand side otherwise that will be syntactically incorrect. For example `{[: string]: number}` would be inconsistent with the syntax of Typescript.

Comment: Just want to add: the identifier does show up in error messages when you run `tsc`, so it might have some use, for lending context or intent. But it doesn't show up in vscode's error tooltips or "Peek Problem" output, FWIW.